# why is Id column not appearing in the CSHTML view in MVC5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm working on a MVC5 project-Code First, in my model the first method is the   Id method (key),when i created the views(list,create,details and delete templates) there was no header cell for the id method,but all other methods in my model have.

Here is my model :

```
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required ")]
        public string First_Name { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required ")]
        public string Last_Name { get; set; }
        public string Birth_Date { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Room Number is required ")]
        public int Room_Number { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime Check_In_Date { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime Check_Out_Date { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Number Of Adults required ")]
        public int Number_Of_Adults { get; set; }
        public Decimal Advanced_Payment { get; set; }

    }
```

and my controller is :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.controlPanels.ToList());
        }



        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View(new ControlPanel());
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(ControlPanel controlPanel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.controlPanels.Add(controlPanel);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            }
            else
            {
                return View(controlPanel);

            }
        }
```

my view is :

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First_Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Last_Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Birth_Date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Room_Number)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Check_In_Date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Check_Out_Date)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Number_Of_Adults)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Advanced_Payment)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
```

I need the Id column to appear automatically when i create the views , as the others appear.
Could you please advise me on the right way to do it ?

Comment: please post your view as well.

Comment: i've included it.

Comment: The reason that id is sensitive data, so by default it will not add it in your view. if you want to display it, you need to manage it manually.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i will try to add it manually.

Comment: it worked as you said, thanks you so much